# UILabel font size fit label width

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

```
type swift
        label.font = UIFont(name: "NanumBarunGothic-YetHangul", size: 10)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Why is the size returned as 10?

My prediction is that the text fits within the width of the UILabel and has a minimum size of 0.5 scale.

Comment: When you don't limit number of lines (i.e. `label.numberOfLines = 0`) there's no reason for label to ever shrink the font (it can instead increase the size of the label by using more lines). If you want to use `label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5` or `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`, specify the finite number of rows, so label will be forced to shrink the font after reaching that number of rows

Comment: What are you asking? Your question seems to be saying: *"I set the font size to 10 ... why is the font size 10?"* Are you actually setting the `.text` of the label to something? Are you setting constraints to control the frame of the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **font size of 10** is used as a starting point, and it can be scaled down as needed to ensure that all the text fits within the label width, while maintaining a minimum font scale factor of 0.5.

Suppose the label text is very short, like "NanumBarun". If the text is small enough to fit within the width of the label object without scaling down the font size, then the font size of 10 will be used as specified in the code. In this case, the **minimumScaleFactor** and **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** properties will not have any effect, and the text will be rendered with the font size of 10 and the remaining space of the label width will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

adjustFontSize will be active when the label doesn't have any space to display (in the case `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false`).

The label will display three dots, ex: `some text...`. If your label has `numberOfLine = 0` and does not have a limit on height, the font does not need to fit because the content still has enough space to display.